# password protect a single file using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, passwords, cpanel, .htpasswd

I have tried to password protect a single file using .htaccess. But when accessing the file the browser just redirects to the home page of the website. I have my .htpasswd on my webroot. My .htaccess file is given below

```
    <FilesMatch "result.php">
    AuthName "Member Only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/username/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
    </FilesMatch>
```

I want to protect the file result.php. I have replaced username with my exact cpanel username. Someone please help

Comment: you don't have any other rules?

Answer (score 12):

```
 <FilesMatch "results.php">
 AuthName "Member Only"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile /home/username/public_html/.htpasswd
 require valid-user
 </FilesMatch>
```

- have to put a full absolute path of the password directory

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example

```
# password protect single file
<IfModule mod_auth.c>
 <Files "protected.html">
  AuthName "Username and password required"
  AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
  AuthType Basic
 </Files>
</IfModule>
```