# Problem Password Protecting a Specific Page/File with .htpasswd and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, passwords, password-protection, .htpasswd

I have a .htpasswd file I created in my home directory, and an existing .htaccess file for all of my site pages. I am trying to password protect only one of these pages.

I tried grouping a new .htaccess file with the file/page I am trying to protect in a subfolder / subdirectory, but the pages start to malfunction (maybe because I used a website builder?).

When I add only the code below into the .htaccess file for the entire website without any more commands, the password protection works / functions properly with the right username/password, but the entire site is password guarded. I am unsure how to target only the one file/webpage rather than targeting my entire website! I have tried a couple different commands such as Location, Files, FilesMatch, but the password protection disappears entirely when I use them.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthUserFile /home/usrname/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [password protect a single file using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570898/password-protect-a-single-file-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<FilesMatch "protected.file.php">
  AuthName "Please Log In"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Note that you need to specify an *absolute* path to the ".htpasswd" file. And that this file should be stored *outside* the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` location inside the file system for security reasons.